# Utilizar 1 campo com chave estrangeira para identificar várias tabelas

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

O que eu gostaria é:

- Criar uma tabela de logs
- Na tabela Logs possuir uma campo ex: FK_ID, onde esse campo identificaria qualquer dado de qualquer tabela. Pois a tabela logs irá possuir os logs de todas as tabelas do sistema.
- Porque se dessa forma não funcionar eu teria que criar uma chave estrangeira na tabela Logs para cada tabela existente no sistema, e isso seria vários campos adicionados a mais na tabela, fora o trabalho de saber qual das FK está preenchida.
- A e não é possível ter uma FK da tabela log em cada tabela, pois o mesmo dado pode ter vários logs.

EX Pratico:
Tab Cliente        Tab Funcionario           Tab Usuario
ID_CLIENTE         ID_FUNCIONARIO            ID_USUARIO

Tab Log
ID_LOG
FK_ID - Aqui iria identificar a tabela pertencente e o dado especifico da tabela pertencente, é possível?

A única forma que eu pensei foi:
Criar o campo FK_ID e inserir o código do dado da tabela especifica
Criar o campo FK_Tabela e inserir o nome da tabela na qual o dado pertence

Assim conseguiria fazer a busca através do código e nome da tabela, mas isso acredito que seja mais uma gambiarra e não uma FK válida de verdade.

Poderiam me ajudar? Agradeceria!

Comment: Não está explicito o que vai guardar na tabela logs, são erros do sistemas dados de tabelas relacionadas? Tem que melhorar essa pergunta....

Comment: Creio que o conceito de uma chave estrangeira é que o valor do campo (ou conjunto de campos) identifique univocamente uma linha de uma outra tabela, e não de possíveis múltiplas tabelas). A sintaxe é `FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn [, ... ] ) ]` ou seja ao criar a constraint foreign key você especifica a tabela referenciada.

Comment: Já consegui resolver pessoal, com a questão de o foreign key ser único, resolvi criar um campo de código e um para identificar a tabela, obrigado!